# Understanding a lib.so crash in android

Tags: android, google-play, crashlytics

I get many crashes in crashlytics which doesn't point to my java/kotlin code.
The crash logs are below

```
Crashed: Thread #1
SIGABRT 0x0000278f000016fc
Crashed: Thread :  SIGABRT  0x0000278f000016fc
#00 pc 0x73fdc8f0f0 libc.so 
#01 pc 0x73fdc8f0c0 libc.so 
#02 pc 0x7378765358 libart.so 
#03 pc 0x73facd4458 libbase.so 
#04 pc 0x73786f228c libart.so 
#05 pc 0x73786f9bb4 libart.so 
#06 pc 0x73787052b8 libart.so 
#07 pc 0x7378772724 libart.so 
#08 pc 0x7378786bbc libart.so 
#09 pc 0x7378785c68 libart.so 
#10 pc 0x73fdcf2890 libc.so 
#11 pc 0x73fdc90b6c libc.so 

Thread #2
Thread
#00 pc 0x73fdcdd084 libc.so 
#01 pc 0x73fdc976b0 libc.so 
#02 pc 0x73fa3a5d14 libbinder.so 
#03 pc 0x73fa3a6ea8 libbinder.so 
#04 pc 0x73fa3a69a4 libbinder.so 
#05 pc 0x73fa39af60 libbinder.so 
#06 pc 0x73fbbcf910 libandroid_runtime.so 

Thread #3
Thread
#00 pc 0x73fdcdd0c4 libc.so 
#01 pc 0x73fdc996c4 libc.so 
#02 pc 0x73628bf148 libjavacrypto.so 
#03 pc 0x73628bf7ec libjavacrypto.so 
#04 pc 0x73628b4d80 libjavacrypto.so 
#05 pc 0x73783ec350 libart.so 
#06 pc 0x73fa75da08 libm.so 
#07 pc 0x73783e445c libart.so 
#08 pc 0x73783e45dc libart.so 
#09 pc 0x7370b65e8c  
#10 pc 0x73783e35b8 libart.so 
#11 pc 0x7370b65e8c  
#12 pc 0x73783f200c libart.so 
#13 pc 0x73783f1fec libart.so 
#14 pc 0x737858f7fc libart.so 
#15 pc 0x737858f7fc libart.so 
#16 pc 0x737858bb0c libart.so 
#17 pc 0x737858b9c8 libart.so 
#18 pc 0x7370b3f742  
#19 pc 0x7378852600 libart.so 
#20 pc 0x7370b3f344  
#21 pc 0x6f677734  
#22 pc 0x6f677738  
#23 pc 0x73783da0fc libart.so 
#24 pc 0x7370b3f742  
#25 pc 0x73783ddc94 libart.so 
#26 pc 0x73785945d4 libart.so 
#27 pc 0x73788502dc libart.so 
#28 pc 0x7370b3f742  
#29 pc 0x7370b3f700  
#30 pc 0x7370b3f700  
#31 pc 0x73783da0fc libart.so 
#32 pc 0x7370b3715c  
#33 pc 0x73783ddb14 libart.so 
#34 pc 0x7370b65ea0  
#35 pc 0x73785945d4 libart.so 
#36 pc 0x7378560b10 libart.so 
#37 pc 0x737883ead8 libart.so 
#38 pc 0x7370b65ea0  
#39 pc 0x7370b65ea0  
#40 pc 0x737883e220 libart.so 
#41 pc 0x7370b3715c  
#42 pc 0x7370b370e4  
#43 pc 0x7370b370e4  
#44 pc 0x7370b65ea0  
#45 pc 0x73783ec468 libart.so 
#46 pc 0x6f73283c  
#47 pc 0x73fa75da08 libm.so 
#48 pc 0x73783e445c libart.so 
#49 pc 0x73783e45dc libart.so 
#50 pc 0x7313055684 base.odex 
#51 pc 0x9d734d94  
#52 pc 0x7313018e38 base.odex 
#53 pc 0x7313052d9c base.odex 
#54 pc 0x9d71bfc4  
#55 pc 0x9d74e644  
#56 pc 0x7313076108 base.odex 
#57 pc 0x9d74e5cc  
#58 pc 0x7312cc1074  
#59 pc 0x9d78bd8c  
#60 pc 0x73130762ac base.odex 
#61 pc 0x9d74e5f4  
#62 pc 0x9d78bf94  
#63 pc 0x73130179f0 base.odex
```

Since we don't use native libraries, seems the libraries are added from plugins (firebase?).
How should I go about understanding where the crash is coming from.

Comment: Did you find any solution regarding this issue, I'm facing the same issue right now.